# Mocking mgo chaining functions

Tags: go, interface, mocking, mgo

While testing some of my codebase I found it useful to mock out objects from "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" with interfaces. I'm running into a problem where mgo.Query does not implement my interface Query.

```
import mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"

type Collection interface {
    FindId(interface{}) Query
    Find(interface{}) Query
    UpdateId(interface{}, interface{}) error
    Update(interface{}, interface{}) error
    UpsertId(interface{}, interface{}) (interface{}, error)
    Insert(...interface{}) error
    RemoveId(interface{}) error
}

type Query interface {
    One(interface{}) error
    All(interface{}) error
    Select(interface{}) Query
}

var _ Query = (*mgo.Query)(nil)
```

The Query cast kicks up the error:

```
cannot use (*mgo.Query)(nil) (type *mgo.Query) as type Query in assignment:
    *mgo.Query does not implement Query (wrong type for Select method)
        have Select(interface {}) *mgo.Query
        want Select(interface {}) Query
```

Is this a problem with chain functions not being able to be defined in an interface? I'm not sure how to make a Select header that will match the mgo implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signatures are different, which is why you're running into a compilation error. Your interface version of `Select` returns *your* `Query` type, while mgo's `Select` returns `*mgo.Query`, which is a different type. Even if that type *does* implement your interface, the function signatures are still different. You will need to add another layer to this where you are able to wrap the mgo package.

```
type MgoQuery struct {
    *mgo.Query
}

func (q *MgoQuery) Select(selector interface{}) Query {
    return q.Query.Select(selector)
}

...
```